# double integration with the same variable

Tags: linear-algebra, integration, indefinite-integrals

I have the integral that I want to resolve. To calculate the flux of the electric machine, I have the following formula:
$v_s= R_s \cdot i_s + \frac{\Phi _s}{dt}$ where $v_s, i_s, \Phi _s$ are voltage, current and electric flux. So to get the flux, I must integrate like this : 
$\phi_s = \int{\left (v_s - R_s \cdot i_s \right )dt}$.
How can I calculate the Laplace Tranform of this flux, and what is the resulat. Thank you.

Comment: To avoid the sort of confusion that you seem to be experiencing now, I would suggest working with definite integrals (possibly with variable limits) than with indefinite integrals. In particular you might write $\phi_s(T)-\phi_s(0)=\int_0^T v_s - R_s \cdot i_s dt$. Then you might take the Laplace transform of $\phi_s(T)-\phi_s(0)$ in the variable $T$.